# PHP pinging, even 1 request timeout

Tags: php, ping

I have been using the script below, however, I want it to ping 3-4 times, and within that 3-4 times if it has even a single request timeout, I want php to come back as failed.

Here's a script I'm using:

```
 <?php

function pingAddressHasNeverFailed($tries) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $tries; $i++) {
        $pingresult = shell_exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com", $outcome, $status);
        if ($status != 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if (pingAddressHasNeverFailed(3)) {
    echo "uoc gi";
}
?>
```

Please help if you can, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Is this going to be used exclusively on Windows?

Comment: no, i'm using on on linux/centos

Comment: Then why are you using `-n 3`? Shouldn't it be `-c 3`?

Comment: I have no idea, it's a script I took from online, no wonder why it does not work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any ping fails (in a set) it will not have `0%` in the output (i.e. `0%` packet loss), which is the same for Linux and Windows:

```
function ping($host, $times = 3)
{
  exec("/bin/ping -c 3 $host", $out, $status);

  return $status === 0 && false !== strpos(join('', $out), '0%');
}

if (ping('www.google.com)) {
  echo "yay\n";
} else {
  echo "oh dear\n";
}
```

You may have to adjust the `ping` arguments to fit your environment and make sure that the host name is sanitized.

Answer (score 2):

In that case you'll need to execute command n (n is a number of tries) times. E.g.:

```
function pingAddressHasNeverFailed($tries) {
    $outcome = array();
    $status = -1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $tries; $i++) {
        $pingresult = exec("/bin/ping -n 1 www.google.com", $outcome, $status);
        if ($status != 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (pingAddressHasNeverFailed(3)) {
    //do something useful
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and got: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: outcome in

Comment: @thevoipman I've copied and pasted your code. Forgot to initialize my local variables. Edited code.

Comment: Also as Jack said youd want to use -c instead of -n on linux.

Comment: i had to use: $pingresult = shell_exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com", $outcome, $status); // then it shows: PHP Warning:  shell_exec() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given

Comment: @thevoipman Yes, `shell_exec` gets only one parameter `string command`. Use `exec`. And yes, this code is for windows, you'll need to modify command for linux.

Comment: how do I get your code to not show: ping: unknown host www.google1.com and just returns false?

Comment: i think this is just part of the display when running as root, but everything else works! thank you